# Ajax request response with 401 post method

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-status-code-401

I am facing problem while requesting url 
In documents for web service access there are required parameters as UserID, queryparam , and header as 
x-requested-by 
 2nd thing I have noticed
I am having my browser url to run code is as
01234.domain_name.com/my form.html
And my request url is as 
09876.domain_name.com/serviceapi/
Where domain_name part is same.
 While posting data I am using code as:

```
URL: 09876.domain_name.com/serviceapi/+ name + '?u=UserID';

$.ajax(function(){
    type: post,
    url: URL,
    data: datajsonobject,
    headers: {x-requested-by: UserID},
    success: successfun
});
```

Code is typing on mobile , please ignore caps lock mistakes in code.

After running this code getting 401 response. Plz help me

Comment: one of my colleague worked on this part and according to him this was due to data problem , data needs to be serialize. now he is saying he is getting 400 error and 401 is resolved. but according to my understandings 401 relates with authentication problem and not with the data I am posting from the form. please guide me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Status code 401 stands for **Unauthorized**. You need to login into your application and then make an Ajax call or your credentials are wrong.
Maybe you can have a debug point in the code where user authentication is being handled.

Comment: Yes, I am getting 401 (unauthorized) response, but plz help me out am I passing param correctly in docs these param defined as name - new folder name that is I am passing through url. Query parameters, with url data - form data, and last x-requested-by header plz guide me the term with credentials = true will this helpful in this case

Comment: When you want to access something(resource) from server, you need to tell server that you are a legitimate user, similar to the case when you login into some website, you pass username and password, server validates your username and password and only then it allows you access other pages and information. Same case here, you need to pass username and password or some other information which will tell server that you are a legitimate user and only then your Ajax call will responded with proper response by the server.

Comment: one of my colleague worked on this part and according to him this was due to data problem , data needs to be serialize. now he is saying he is getting 400 error and 401 is resolved. but according to my understandings 401 relates with authentication problem and not with the data I am posting from the form. please guide me if I am wrong.